# data handling while using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running into issue wherein the first time if user wants to plot graph it works fine, but if same option is selected again I see an error as below. To me it seems some of the resources held by pyplot are not getting released. Is my understanding correct if so, how to correct it ? and if wrong what would be possible cause for it ?

Just bit more info - it only happens if I try to plot graph - if I just want to display data it works fine.

Code:

```
default_options = {'0' : 'Below are the options',
                   '1' : '1 . Enter File path\'s for processing',
                   '2' : '2 . Display all categories',
                   '3' : '3 . Display type of forms',
                   '4' : '4 . Display for given form annual result',
                   '5' : '5 . Compare two form annual result ',
                   '6' : '6 . Compare two years annual result',
                   '99': '0 . Type 0 to exit '
                   }

labels = ["1st_quat", "2nd_quat", "3rd_quat", "4th_quat"]

def plotBarGraph(self, fiscal_year):
    index = np.arange(len(labels))
    bar_width = 0.1
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    appli_received = [data[0] for data in fiscal_year]
    appli_accepted = [data[1] for data in fiscal_year]
    appli_denied = [data[2] for data in fiscal_year]
    appli_pending = [data[3] for data in fiscal_year]

    plt.bar(index, appli_received, bar_width, alpha = 0.5, color='b')
    plt.bar(index + bar_width, appli_accepted,bar_width, alpha = 0.5, color='r')
    plt.bar(index + bar_width * 2, appli_denied, bar_width, alpha = 0.5, color='g')
    plt.bar(index + bar_width * 3,  appli_pending,bar_width, alpha = 0.5, color='k')
    plt.xticks(index, labels, rotation = 35)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major')
    plt.legend(['Received', 'Approved', 'Denied', 'Pending'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

def getUserInput(self):
    self.displayUserOption()
    user_input = int(raw_input())
    if self.validateUserInput(user_input):
        if user_input:
            self.processForAllFile(user_input)
            self.getUserInput()
    else:
        print " Please enter valid option \n "
        self.getUserInput()
```

Error printed when user tries to plot graph again( I manually close the plot as well before selecting to plot it again)

```
self.plotBarGraph(report)

    plt.bar(index, appli_received, bar_width, alpha = 0.5, color='b')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2089, in bar
    ret = ax.bar(left, height, width, bottom, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4733, in bar
    nbars)
AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 4 or scalar
```

Comment: In order to understand what's going on, it looks like we need to see the code for `plotBarGraph`

Comment: @mobiusklein - I have updated question with code as requested

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a mismatch between the `labels` variable, which appears to be global, and the dimensions of `fiscal_year` in `plotBarGraph`. The dimensions of the variable `index` depends up the length of `labels`. You then flatten `fiscal_year` into lists of unknown dimensions and try to use them as heights for a bar graph with exactly `len(labels)` bars.

When `len(labels) != len(fiscal_year)`, there are too many or too few heights for `matplotlib` to correctly draw a bar plot, which is why you're seeing the error you're seeing.

Comment: As I said it works first time - only if I select the option again it does not work and throws out the error. As you can see from my code, user can select same option multiple times, so for the first time things are good , its second time it runs into error

Comment: Can you confirm that the value of `labels` is consistent with the value in `fiscal_year`? How does the value of `labels` get set?

Comment: I have updated labels value- Yes its a global variable. Sorry but I am not able to understand if it works for first time, why would mapping has to do anything for second time around - no data has changed, only same request has came second time. It would be great to understand your point which I am missing

Comment: In your `plotBarGraph` function, the variable `index` is defined by the length of `labels`. Then, you use elements of the argument `fiscal_year` to build some lists and use them for a bar graph. The assumption for `ax.bar` is that the `left` and `height` arguments are the same length. Because we can't see how `plotBarGraph` is called, it's hard to say why they don't line up. Can you print their values on each call?